# How can I check if an element is found and not found in an array by reading its value (content)

Tags: java

Question:

Complete the program so that it asks the user for a number to search in the array. If the array contains the given number, the program tells the index containing the number. If the array doesn't contain the given number, the program will advise that the number wasn't found.

My code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[8];
        array[0] = 6;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 8;
        array[3] = 1;
        array[4] = 3;
        array[5] = 0;
        array[6] = 9;
        array[7] = 7;

        int searchValueInput = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int loopValue = 0; loopValue < array.length; loopValue++) {
            if (searchValueInput == array[loopValue]) {
                System.out.println(searchValueInput + " is at index " + loopValue + ".");
            } else if (searchValueInput > array.length) {
                System.out.println(searchValueInput + " was not found.");
            }
        }
```

I have modified my code to a simpler logic, because I have complicated it a lot. I have also defined the problem and it is as follows:

How can I check if an element value is inside an array (**this part is already done I believe**)

How can I check if an element value is not found within the array (**this is the part I am missing**)

The output result should look similar to the following:

```
Search for? 3
3 is at index 4.

Search for? 9
9 is at index 6.

Search for? 22
22 was not found.
```

Comment: The title is written to suggest we should search outside the array but the problem statement doesn't seem to require that. The second thing I noticed was the logic written inside the for loop... Have you tried rereading and reworking that?

Comment: This line is your problem: `else if (searchValueInput > array[loopValue])`. If you enter a number that is greater than any value in the array, the search will stop at that point.

Comment: @JimRhodes, where is the problem in that? I want the search to stop and print the searchValueInput was not found if it was bigger than the array values.

Comment: The problem is that the first array value you reach that is less than the input will cause your search to stop too soon. For example, if you enter 3, the search will stop as soon as it sees the value 2 at index 1.

Comment: @clwhisk, Hi, do excuse me for the confusion and complication. I have modified my code and the missing part here is that I need to check if an element value is not within the array. Please take a look at my modification

Comment: @JimRhodes, I have been able to narrow down the problem and defined it. The only thing that I am missing is that I want to check if the element value is not within a range by printing "not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Complete explanation

You should extract searching the array to a method.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example {
// 1
    public static int search(int[] arr, int target){
        
        // 2 
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            // 3
            if(arr[i]==target)
                // 4
                return i;

        }
        // 5
        return -1; 
    }

// 6
    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        int[] arr = {4,3,2,1,6,5,7,8,9,0};
        int index = search(arr, 4);
        if(index >= 0)
            System.out.println("Element found at " + index);
        else 
            System.out.println("Element can't be found");
    }
}
```

1. Start the method definition.
2. Loop through the array, with the index `i` starting from 0.
3. Check if `arr[i]` is equal to the target being searched for.
4. If `true` return the index. (Function ends here)
5. Return `-1` if the index can't be found.
6. Driver code

Comment: Hi there, creating and calling another method did complicate my problem. I have tried implementing your code, it did not work as I have been requested to. I still need to assign an inputValue to replace the target parameter. Can I assign the index to the array[loopValue] and inputValue (which is searchingValueInput)

Comment: You can take the target input by using the `Scanner` class. I just showed the logic you can use to find a target as example.

Comment: the program functions as requested. However, it is printing the return values for me. Both returns i and -1 are being printed in the output, how can I exclude them from printing out?

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. In addition to that, is there a more simpler way to solve the problem without creating and calling another method? If you could give me a hint for that so I can work it on my own. All the best

Comment: @belinyom I literally answered as you asked, Check all the answer you got

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code does compare between your input value and the value inside the array, such as if the value you input is greater than the value inside the array it spits out "Not found"

I'm not sure if I undestood the problem correctly, try the following code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] array = {6,2,8,1,3,0,9,7,0,0};

System.out.println("Search for? ");
int searchValueInput = scanner.nextInt();
boolean found = false;
for (int loopValue = 0; loopValue < array.length; loopValue++) {
    if (array[loopValue] == searchValueInput) {
        System.out.println(searchValueInput + " is at index " + loopValue + ".");
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found)
    System.out.println(searchValueInput + " was not found.");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

this part in the original code makes no sense

```
if (searchValueInput > array.length) {
                System.out.println(searchValueInput + " was not found.");
            }
```

below code should work

```
   static String findSame(int[] intArr, int num) {
        for(int i = 0; i<intArr.length;i++) {
            if(intArr[i]==num) {
                return num + " is at index "+i;
            }
        }
        return num + " was not found.";
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Search for?");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int[] array = new int[8];
        array[0] = 6;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 8;
        array[3] = 1;
        array[4] = 3;
        array[5] = 0;
        array[6] = 9;
        array[7] = 7;

        int searchValueInput = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(findSame(array, searchValueInput));
    }
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly clear. However, when you return num + a string, how can you return that value with a string to its method? Java does not accept that...

Comment: adding an integer to string will cast that integer to string. for example         ```int a = 5;
        String b = a + "";
        System.out.println(b);``` will work